# Scripting java : Create a class in a script file

Tags: java, scripting, mozilla, rhino, java-6

I want to create a java class in a script file (javax.script). please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [Google](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=pqQ&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&&sa=X&ei=VKIfTNSsO4P-8AbKyfHJDA&ved=0CBkQvwUoAQ&q=java+scripting&spell=1)?

First 2 results:

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/scripting/

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/index.html

Comment: The thing that I want to do is creating a class in the script (in my script file, and use it like a java class) this is all what I need. I don't  want to import a class from my project, but I need to create it in the script. how to do ???

Comment: The best that you can do is create a Javascript object, cast it to invokable, and do it from there. However unless your doing some kind of plugin system, you are kinda breaking some OOP rules

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.*;
public class Employee{
 String name;
 int age;
 String designation;
 double salary;

 public Employee (String name){
  this.name=name;
 } 
 public void empAge(int empAge){
  age=empAge;
 }
 public void empDesignation(String empDesig){
  designation=empDesig;
 }
 public void empSalary(double empSalary){
  salary=empSalary;
  }
 public void printEmployee(){
  System.out.println("Name:         "+name);
  System.out.println("Age:          "+age);
  System.out.println("Designation:  "+designation);
  System.out.println("Salary:       "+salary);

 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class WesternTown {

     int stables;
     int saloon;
     int yearEstablished;
     int troublemaker;
     String sheriffsname;
     String location;


     public WesternTown() {
         stables=3;
         location="Wesrtern America";
         yearEstablished=1850;
     }

     public WesternTown(String name) {
         sheriffsname = name;
     } 


     public static void main (String [] args){

         WesternTown newtown = new WesternTown();
         WesternTown newname = new WesternTown("SHERIFFER");
         System.out.println("stables:      " + newtown.stables);
         System.out.println("saloon:       " + newtown.saloon );
         System.out.println("sheriffs:     " + newtown.sheriffsname ); 
         System.out.println("troublemaker: " + newtown.troublemaker );
         System.out.println("location:     " + newtown.location );
         System.out.println("yearEstablished: " + newtown.yearEstablished );
         System.out.println("The Name is:     " + newname.sheriffsname );
     }
}
```